# Is there a Slavic equivalent of the Greek and Latin semantic transfer from "chest/vault" to "treasure", like θησαυρός/thesaurus?

Tags: etymology, romance-languages, slavic-languages, romanian

I was looking at the etymology of the Romanian word [comoară](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comoar%C4%83) ("treasure", "hoard", "pile of precious things") and it seems based on the widespread Slavic form [komora](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/komora), meaning "room", "container", "chamber" and other semantically related notions. But I cannot find a case where this or a related form would mean "treasure", on the model of the Latin *thesaurus* and Greek *θησαυρός*, with this basic semantic coincidence or transfer between content (treasure) and recipient (treasury, box, strongbox).

I was thus very surprised watching [an Italian movie where a seemingly  slang or invented word in the *romanesco* dialect means "strongbox" but sounds close to Romanian *comoară*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/14262/5860). All that leads nowhere though, as it seems.

Therefore, I am still intrigued: ***is the Romanian word the only member of that group of words in Eastern Europe which means "treasure"?*** ---no matter the ultimate supposedly Latin origin of all of them - from *camera*---

---

It is to be noted that:

- the word *[kamera](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kamera#Etymology_8)* (Romanian *camera*) present in many Slavic languages, including Russian, has to be considerd separately, as a neologism equivalent to the Italian word *camera* - usually including the somewhat ”modern” meanings of ”room” (sometimes in a technical sense), ”legislative body” and ”photographic camera”
- Bulgarian *[kamara](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0#Bulgarian)* seems to be not one word, but three different words, although similar in form: one, pronounced `'kamərə`, means “legislative body” and is of Turkish origin; a second one is an archaism, has the same pronunciation, means “chamber, vaulted room” and is of Slavic origin; [a third one](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0#Etymology_3) is pronounced `kɐˈmarə`, means “pile, heap” , ”a load”, ”a ton of” something, and supposedly is of Greek origin. This might be the only case that looks close to the Romanian one: that transfer from generic-Slavic ”chamber” (*camera*/*komora*) to  ”a pile of stuff” (*kamara*-'kamərə`) seems *based* on (mediated by) Romanian ”pile of gold” (*comoară*).

---

(By the way, how solid is the Latin etymology for *komora* in Polish, Czech, Macedonian etc? Are these forms recent neologisms -like *kamera* is-, or are they old Slavic forms - even if ultimately from Latin? - Couldn't there be a direct Proto-Slavic < [PIE origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/kh%E2%82%82em)?)

Comment: PIE _*kh₂em-_ “to bend, to curve” > Proto-Balto-Slavic _*kam-_ > Proto-Slavic _*kǫ̃-_ as in _*kǫ̃-tъ_ “corner” (Ukrainian _кут_ (kut), Bulgarian _кът_ (kǎt), Czech: _kout_), so the direct derivation of _komora_ from PIE _*kh₂em-_ is highly unlikely.

Comment: @YellowSky - But *komora* is old word in Slavic languages (e.g. Polish), right? - unlike *kamera*.

Comment: Yes, _komora_ is a borrowing into Proto-Slavic from Latin or Greek, it can be seen by the _a_ > _o_ correspondence.

Comment: @YellowSky - This is clear to me now. I think I will have to edit the question and remove my "doubts" about this part, and let the focus on the main part as put in the title. My interest is whether the Romanian word could be a reflection of the Greek, Latin and Neo-Latin structure but under the Slavic form, or whether that structure is in fact rather common, also present in Slavic languages (although I wasn't able to find it).